Could I take refuge in an embassy after commiting a crime?
This is just a hypothetical that I am curious about, but I don't see a definite answer for this anywhere which is surprising.
So, lets say I am in India, and then I get into a confrontation where I have no choice but to defend myself (I am saying this because the US recognizes self-defense, and even though India does as well, its not as definite). And then, lets say that, the police are looking to arrest me, could I flee to a US Embassy to seek refuge there?
What would happen?

This is a legal question and not a political one.

I second the notion that this is a legal question. But a way to make it a political one is to clarify what your citizenship is in this scenario. The manner that US diplomacy will handle things in such a situation would hinge substantially on your citizenship.

@JoeW, the legal part of the question is easy. The political part is difficult -- does the ambassador want to involve his or her country in a crisis?

@o.m. That doesn't mean it is a valid question for this site as there are so many different variables that would factor into that decision that it would be impossibly broad.

Nah, this seems like a valid enough question about inter-state relations and diplomatic prerogatives.  For one thing, international law, as is often said here, isn't the same thing as national laws.  For another that the ambassy is largely in the right to grant asylum, but is unlikely to do so in this  instance, so the legal environment is not the full answer.

Suggestion: Migrate to Law

This is only tangentially related to the embassy status question but there are several flaws in your pretext scenario. First, self-defense is typically an excuse or legal defense, it doesn't mean there should be no investigation and no trial. And that's clearly for Indian courts to judge, why would the US definition(s) or your personal feeling that it was self-defense override the Indian legal system and justify preempting any proceedings?

Surely, if at the end of the day an Indian judge considers it wasn't self-defense, it means that you did have a choice, at least in the eyes of the Indian legal system. It seems this whole self-defense thing is a red herring, the question is whether you can escape the law by entering an embassy.

@JoeW the ambassador's decision about whether to shelter the fugitive is entirely political.

@Pyrotechnical it's not necessary to specify citizenship to make this a political question; the country whose embassy it is can respond to this situation basically however they want, and the decision about how to respond is political.

@phoog Not necessary,  as there are a lot of legal reasons in it that involve all sorts of different treaties and what the crime is. If that is the route you want to go it would be closed as overly broad as there are way to many different factors in that could change the answer. The same crime could be committed by different people, in different countries, or with different victims and the actions as a result can be completely different.  The only real answer we can give is it depends on the circumstances.

It probably comes down to the internal politics of the country whose embassy is offering asylum. What importance do you have to them or to their foreign policy? What political issue important to the country of the embassy does your plight exemplify?

An embassy is considered extraterritorial territory. The police of the host country cannot enter (without the permission of the ambassador), and cannot arrest anybody (without the permission of the ambassador). If the host country gets seriously upset about the actions of the embassy, they can take various steps to make things unpleasant for the occupants of the embassy. In relatively recent history, consider

Manuel Noriega in the Vatican embassy for 10 days,
Julian Assange in the Ecuadorian embassy for 7 years.

The questions, then, does the fugitive believe that the ambassador will let him in, and is the fugitive right or will the ambassador throw him out? Usually, the answer to the second part is that an embassy will not antagonize the host country.

You should probably add that embassies generally cooperate with local authorities unless there is an exceptional reason not to. This is both practical and political: no one wants minor crimes to escalate to diplomatic incidents, and embassies and their staffs depend on the cooperation of locals. So unless the person in question is high-profile or there is a clear and obvious injustice occurring, they will almost certainly be turned over to police.

@TedWrigley, added.

I'm not sure how many (if any) legal jurisdictions approach missions as genuinely extraterritorial. The protection of the premises as inviolable does follow from section 22 of the Vienna Convention on Diplomatic Relations (https://legal.un.org/ilc/texts/instruments/english/conventions/9_1_1961.pdf) and breaking that is a good way for a state to lose all support from the international community.

Even in the case of nominally-immune diplomatic staff there is often an expectation that the embassy collaborates in normal, apolitical, matters.  For example, there was a big hullaballoo in the 80s? 90s? when a drunk senior Soviet diplomat ran over someone in the US and was packed off home.  Ditto when the wife of a US diplomat ran over a young man in the UK 5 yrs or so back.  I don't know how often diplomats do get handed over in these cases, but the OP's situation is unlikely to work out to the claimant's benefit.

@origimbo, see my examples. It can be done, but it usually triggers a diplomatic crisis.

(+1) Where does the phrase “extraterritorial territory” comes from and what is it supposed to mean? Do you simply mean it enjoys the immunity you describe? I am familiar with the concept of extraterritoriality or extraterritorial rights, but “extraterritorial territory” seems nonsensical. Also note that embassies or consulates can be in apartment buildings, again not really “territory” in any usual sense of the word.

@ItalianPhilosopher Depends a lot on the sending country. Some countries have diplomat pay their fines, others do not. The US is not among the most cooperating, I am not sure they ever handed over a diplomat, embassy staff, or relative. Best case scenario, if the matter is serious, they get prosecuted in the US or, as in the Harry Dunn case, appear in foreign court via video link.

@Relaxed Yes, "extraterriorality" usually means the jurisdiction of one country applying outside that country's borders. This is not the case of embassies; the host country law still applies, what happens is that (absent invitation from the diplomatic personnel), the host country security forces cannot enter to enforce it. I think that the correct term is "protected".

Embassies are not extraterritorial.  They are inviolable.  There is a big difference.

@SJuan76 the term in the Vienna Convention is "inviolable."  The laws of both the sending country and the receiving (a.k.a. host) country apply in an embassy, but, as you note, the host authorities cannot enter an embassy without permission of the ambassador.  "Extraterritorial" typically means that the embassy is actual territory of the sending country, which is, as you note, not how embassies are generally treated.

Assange was in the embassy for 7 years (June 2012 to April 2019).

@SteveMelnikoff, thanks, corrected.

@phoog Would "extraterritorial" apply to military bases located in foreign countries?

@Barmar normally not.  Extraterritoriality means that the territory in question is entirely removed from the jurisdiction of the country.  The most straightforward example of this is the provision for Princess Margriet of the Netherlands not to become a British subject by virtue of jus soli when she was born in Ottawa.  The maternity ward of the hospital was made extraterritorial to achieve this.  The status of any given foreign military base, however, will depend on an agreement between the country using the base and the country hosting it.  But true foreign bases are fairly rare.

@Barmar, the status of such bases (and troops off-base) is usually negotiated in so-called Status of Forces Agreements (SOFA). For instance, the usual NATO SOFA specifies that deployment orders and military ID substitute for passport and visa for immigration purposes.
